# Cannot install tensorflow.js via npm

Tags: npm, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, tensorflow.js

Whenever I try to install the package I get the following error. I initially used the method as documented on the tensorflow website to no avail. Furthermore, I tried installing with yarn and the script tag and that did not work as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> npm install @tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.1

works fine for me, so just install version 0.11.1 instead of 0.11.2

Comment: It worked although I tried it earlier and it didn’t. Thanks!